# Logstash truncating message breaks when too large, what is upper limit?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to truncate logs like this

```
if [message] =~ /.{10000000,}/ {
    truncate {
        fields => "message"
        length_bytes => 10000000
        add_tag => [ "truncated_msg" ]
    }
}
```

My logstash pipeline breaks with this error

```
"exception"=>"too big number for repeat range: /.{10000000,}/"
```

Question:

What is the upper limit?

Comment: Which version of Logstash do you have? And why not simply removing the if condition? truncate wouldn't do anything anyway if your message is shorter

Comment: can't you just directly call the truncate without the `if [message] =~ /.{10000000,}/`? That'd solve the issue with the limit

Comment: And it seems the limit is 100,000, it's a limit from the JDK. Limit: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/37115c8ea4aff13a8148ee2b8832b20888a5d880/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/regexp/joni/Config.java#L49 and https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/37115c8ea4aff13a8148ee2b8832b20888a5d880/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/regexp/joni/Lexer.java#L98